# Xamarin Masked Input Delay

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have an Entry control in Xaml that uses a converter to mask the user's input to two decimal places.

The issue is that there is a slight delay when typing in the field.

How can I improve performance to remove this delay?

Xaml:

```
<local:CustomEntry Text="{Binding Weight, Converter={StaticResource decimalConverter}}" Keyboard="Numeric"></local:CustomEntry>
```

Converter:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return Decimal.Parse(value.ToString()).ToString("0.00");
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            string valueFromString = Regex.Replace(value.ToString(), @"\D", "");

            if (valueFromString.Length <= 0)
                return 0m;

            long valueLong;
            if (!long.TryParse(valueFromString, out valueLong))
                return 0m;

            if (valueLong <= 0)
                return 0m;

            return valueLong / 100m;
        }
```

Comment: You posted this already.  Did you try the suggestions made in the prior post?

Comment: Yes, but the delay was still present